# Pass two byte array to asp.net web api post method

Tags: c#, arrays, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have two byte array in the angularjs application. I want to pass two byte array to api end point in the body as a post operation.

```
       function getPayload(byteArray1, byteArray2) {
                return {
                    "byteArrayInfo1": byteArray1,
                    "byteArrayInfo2": byteArray2
                };
            }

        var executePostRequest = function (command, byteArray1, byteArray2) {
                    return $http({
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' },
                        data: getPayload(byteArray1,byteArray2),
                        url: env.endPointBasePath + command
                    });
            };
```

When i am debugging to dot net api end point, it is not getting two byte array. I tried changing content-type to 'Content-Type': 'application/json'. It did not work.

My concern here is now, is it good to try to pass two byte array in one post call? Is it good practice? I would be happy if there is technique in javascript/angularjs to merge two byte arrays and split in app api end point.

App api end point is self hoisted owin based appliation. I was trying to retrive the body from context request body and map it to ByteArrayPayload class.

```
private static ByteArrayPayload ExtractContent(OwinContext context)
    {
        if (ContentLengthIsNullOrZero(context.Request.Headers.ContentLength))
        {
            return null;
        }

        int contentLength = Int32.Parse(context.Request.Headers.ContentLength);
        var content = context.Request.Body.Read(contentLength);
       //map content to ByteArrayPayload 
       return new ByteArrayPayload ();
    }

  public class ByteArrayPayload{
    public byte[] ByteArrayInfo1 {get;set;}
    public byte[] ByteArrayInfo2 {get;set;}
  }
```

Comment: Will you post your controller code too

Comment: When you say "byte array", do you mean an [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ArrayBuffer) object?

Comment: The best way to send binary content is by using an [ArrayBufferView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBufferView) or [Blobs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). The [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) can be used to send multiple binary items but is inefficient because the [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding adds 33% extra overhead.

Comment: I updated my app api end point code in one of middle ware i wanted to map the body content.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to send binary content is by using an [ArrayBufferView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBufferView) or [Blobs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). The [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) can be used to send multiple binary items such as `application/octet-stream` but is inefficient because the [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) encoding adds 33% extra overhead.

For more information, see [MDN Web API Reference - XHR Send Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send).